# Can't reinstall Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

so I was using Ubuntu 19.10 (dual-booted with UEFI Windows 10) and decided to upgrade as it is going out of support in a month. It ran flawlessly, but when I did the system upgrade to 20.04LTS, it went fine but shortly after booting into the new OS the system froze and now only boots to a black screen.

I booted a live USB in UEFI mode and selected the option to "reinstall Ubuntu" (keeps data). The installer detects both Ubuntu and Windows installed on the system.
[Setup info pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu6Ri.jpg)

When I click next, the installer says "No EFI System Partition was found". When I go to make one (500 MB), I've tried selecting the entire drive and just the EFI Partition to no avail.
[No EFI Partition pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN0PR.jpg)
[Partition manager pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTkkO.jpg)

It says this: "Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/boot/efi): /dev/nvme0n1p2 and /dev/nvme0n1p2. Please correct this by changing mount points."
[Same mount points error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4jZQ.jpg)

I know for a fact that my Windows 10, old Ubuntu 19.10, and Live USB are all in UEFI mode.

Any help would be appreciated. Worst case scenario I backed up my home folder and could reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

So I decided after 2 days of googling around this problem that I can't have my main machine down any longer. Everything I've found related to my issues either hasn't worked or the OP just ended up reinstalling.

So; I bit the bullet and reinstalled. Everything seems to be going smoothly so far and my home directory files are in place. It's a shame about all my customizations, apps, dependencies and libraries that were installed, but I still have my data.

I'm almost definitely going to be staying on this LTS release for the life of this computer since I don't want any more hiccups.

Thanks,
Hunter